# change attribute name in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, alias

this is my original table.

```
+----------+---------------------+--------+------------+-------+
| lab_code | test_name           | sample | time_taken | price |
+----------+---------------------+--------+------------+-------+
| FBS      | Fasting blood Suagr | Blood  | 01:15:00   |   400 |
| STLC     | Stool Culture       | Stool  | 48:00:00   |   700 |
| UA       | Urinalysis          | Urine  | 02:30:00   |   425 |
| UDS      | Urine drug screen   | Urine  | 06:00:00   |   550 |
+----------+---------------------+--------+------------+-------+
```

i want to display

```
+----------+
| Hospital | 
+----------+
| FBS      | 
| STLC     | 
| UA       | 
| UDS      | 
+----------+
```

i want to change attibute name when data Quering.(without changing original table)
plz help.

Comment: the term is Column aliasing

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no research effort

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give `ALIAS` name to specific column

```
SELECT lab_code AS Hospital 
From tableA
```

Comment: @7evenline You're most welcome. Take a tour of stackoverflow on http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
SELECT lab_code AS Hospital FROM <table_name>;
```

The use of AS is an **ALIAS** that can be used for the column name; it does not mean that the table's column name changes, but rather, when the SELECT query is executed, that becomes the column name or alias for the current column name present in the table.

Comment: @7evenline No problems.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT lab_code AS Hospital From original_table
```

it will work with and without `AS`

```
SELECT lab_code Hospital From original_table
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

`aliases` are used to temporarily rename a column name (or table name in other cases)

```
SELECT lab_code AS Hospital FROM Table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT lab_code AS Hospital

FROM Original_Table
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT "lab_code" AS "Hospital" FROM "table";
```

Answer (score 1):

If lab_code  isn't primary key use this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT lab_code AS Hospital 
FROM myTable
```